# Can I create alerts on document folders using MS Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When you view document folders in a SharePoint online site you have the ability to configure email alerts on folders based on when items are added or deleted. Can I do the same thing via the Microsoft Graph API? If this is not possible now, is there any plan to add this to the API in the near future? The only workaround I have been able to come up with involves using the Delta API to poll for changes periodically, but that requires a lot of processing as the Delta API is not very granular.

Answer (score 1):

You do this using webhooks and registering a subscription against the resource you want to monitor.

See [Using webhooks to receive service-to-service notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/using-webhooks) for details and examples of how this works.